# Github: Allow force pushes to specific users/groups

Tags: github

Is there any rule that can be configured on GitHub that restricts who can force-push? The way it looks right now is that any rule opened on any branch automatically prevents force-pushes to anyone (including administrators). I want to  allow force-pushes to specific users/groups (e.g., administrators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [Tomerfi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10025838/tomerfi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944052/6309), since Dec. 2021:

> ### [Specify who can force push to a repository](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-21-specify-who-can-force-push-to-a-repository/)
>
> Instead of allowing all or no users to force push, admins can now be selective about who can force push to a repository.
>
> The image below shows how in the past, admins could use a branch protection rule to allow force pushes for everyone or no one, including admins:
>
> Branch protection rule to allow everyone or no one to force push:
>
> [image: https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1767415/146840069-87f0c92a-527d-4b93-97a1-8ce9532022b1.png?ssl=1]
>
> This all-or-nothing approach didn't support limiting force pushes to select users or teams of an admin's choosing.
> For example, you might have wanted to allow only a few people to force push, or you had an automated process that solely needed to force push.
>
> Now, you can be specific about the people and teams who are allowed to force push.
>
> As shown in the image below, select Allow force pushes and Specify who can force push. Then, search for and select the people and teams who should be allowed to force push.
>
> Branch protection rule to allow everyone, no one, or select users or teams to force push:
>
> [image]
>
> For more information, visit [Managing a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule).

---

Original answer (2019):

You can't directly setup that on GitHub.

You can setup different repositories though:

- one where you can force push
- one where the branch is protected to everyone.

Then you can make PR (Pull Request) from one repository to another.

Comment: Not really a usable strategy for us, but  thanks for the clear alternative suggestion

Answer (score 2):

This is now actually supported on GitHub:

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-21-specify-who-can-force-push-to-a-repository/

Comment: Good catch. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30963024)